# Weld (CDI): where do I put my test-only beans.xml that configures <alternatives>?

Tags: jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

My webapp has a non-empty production `beans.xml` under `src/main/resources/META-INF`.
Now, for my tests, I need to swap out 1 bean with an alternative.

Where do I put this test `beans.xml` which contains just this and nothing more?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
  <alternatives>
    <class>...MyTestReplacement</class>
  </alternatives>
</beans>
```

I tried under `src/test/resources/META-INF` but that is ignored. I am using arquillian and my test classpath is added to the ShrinkWrap.

Comment: Note: using `ShrinkWrap...addAsManifestResource(new File("target/test-classes/META-INF/test-beans.xml"), "beans.xml")` does not work, because it overwrites the original `beans.xml` (which is quite large) and that needs to be activated too.

Comment: Looks like there 's no answer, so I 've opened an issue: [https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-585](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-585)

Comment: Asked on [the seam forum](http://www.seamframework.org/Community/UsingAnAlternativeBeanInTestsWhereToDeclareAlternative) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use @Alternative, but use @Specializes. Just put the @Specializes bean only in your test classpath and it will automatically replace the real bean. No need to mess around with beans.xml.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it's already accepted, ill post you the solution I found. I had the same problem, and using @Specializes was no option for me, because I had many mocks with several  methods, thus create for each one a class was a bit overkill....

So in my test I have a ResourceMock:

```
@Produces
@Alternative
public IResource createResource() {
    Resource resource = mock(Resource.class);
    when(resource.getLocalized(anyString())).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
    return resource;
}
```

With the following ShrinkWrap I was able to load those @Alternative bean only during the test: (no beans.xml in the test dir needed!)

```
return ShrinkWrap
            .create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, "some.package.with.classes")
            .addAsManifestResource(
                    new StringAsset(
                            "<alternatives><class>my.testclass.with.alternatives</class></alternatives>"),
                    "beans.xml");
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you need to use @Alternative, you can use a shrinkwrap command `.alternativeClass`. You can see the following example in the Arquillian-showcase, cdi-ejb subproject.  Include this dependency in your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then use this type of @Deployment (for Glassfish):

```
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeploymentForGlassFish() {
    BeansDescriptor beansXml = Descriptors.create(BeansDescriptor.class);

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(FireAndForget.class, FireAndForgetBean.class, BlockingFireAndForgetAlternativeBean.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(
                    new StringAsset(beansXml.alternativeClass(BlockingFireAndForgetAlternativeBean.class).exportAsString()),
                    beansXml.getDescriptorName());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

See http://seamframework.org/Seam3/ModuleTesting or http://ocpsoft.com/seam/cdi-powered-unit-testing-using-arquillian/

Comment: These links explain basic usage with arquillian, but neither of which answer the question.

Comment: They show how you tell arquillian which configs to use. Or you can provide the content directly without extra file.

Comment: Problem is that, in both cases, it overwrites the original beans.xml. Duplicating the entire content of the original beans.xml into the test-beans.xml is not maintainable (and violates DRY).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the code from bellow to specify which `beans.xml` file to include:

```
JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(AutoService.class, AutoServiceCallerImp1.class, AutoServiceCallerImp2.class)
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test.beans.xml", "beans.xml");
```