# CDI @Alternative - choosing alternatives per test cases

Tags: java, testing, cdi

I'm wondering how to specify which mock implementation should be used during testing while using CDI.

I know that I can mark a mock implementation with @Alternative, but then I'd need to define it in beans.xml. I would like to have multiple mocks (for multiple objects). Lets say I have an OrderService and a EmailService. I'm writing some acceptance tests where I do not want EmailService to send emails. Then the other set of tests which are system tests - where I do want to send emails, but real order should not be created.

The ideal solution would be to specify Alternatives per each test method invocation, something like this:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void before(){
  // in this test suite we're using mock email service
  addAlternative(MockEmailService.class);
}
@Test
public void testMyStuff(){
  issueAnOrder(); // and verify that it worked. no emails sent!
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't used the Java EE CDI implementation - I've been using, and have so far stuck with Spring for dependency injection, but...A common idiom is to use dependency injection for the application, but to explicitly set up the dependencies in a test class - either in the BeforeMethod if all test methods will use the same mock, or directly at the beginning of the test method if different test methods will use different mocks.

Comment: I know where to do it, I have even pasted that part of the code... The question is HOW to inject something else - how to override the "default" bean.

Comment: Again, I don't know the specifics of Java EE CDI off the top of my head, but presumably your test isn't doing CDI (or you can disable it). Then just use either constructor parameters, or accessor methods, as required to set mocked properties.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: I think you're talking about unit tests, but i suspect mabn is talking about integration tests, or whatever you want to call them, where some of the components are the real things. There, you need to lean on the injection framework, rather than injecting everything by hand, which is where this problem comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a combination of @Alternative/@Specialisation and Arquillian. [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) provides new possibilities for integration testing and enables you to specify different Alternatives for each test, by altering the "beans.xml". Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349045/weld-cdi-where-do-i-put-my-test-only-beans-xml-that-configures-alternatives) question for concrete details.

Comment: Although Arquillian is indeed a very useful tool for testing CDI and/or JEE apps, it is meant for integration testing. Sometimes though you just need to write a fast, lean and mean unit test for a CDI class. My answer below describes how you can achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

CDI-Unit has built in support for mocking http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/
Just use specify the mock as a producer field in your test class.

```
class Starship {

  @Inject
  Engine engine; //This will be mocked

  void start() {
    engine.start();
  }
}


@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
class TestStarship {

  @Inject
  Starship starship;

  @Produces
  @Mock // Mockito will create a mock for us.
  Engine engine;

  @Test
  public void testStart() {
    starship.start();

    // Verify that the mocks start method is called at least once.
    Mockito.verify(engine, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally we've migrated from spring 2.0 to 3.2 (instead of CDI) and we're using springockito to mock/spy on spring beans.

Answer (score 0):

Roland probably the best acceptable answer, another possible one is to create a portable extension that will read some property you setup in the test or the environment and ProcessAnnotatedType.veto() the versions you don't want.

Another option with Arquillian is simply not to bundle all the alternatives and have multiple deployments to choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by configuring the CDI-container programmatically in your test.

To do so, set `disableDiscoveryMode()` on your CDI-container in your test class, add the neccesary classes for your test to the container (at least your test subject **and** the alternative class) and add the alternative class as being alternative.

Below an example. Greeter is my test subject, Greeting is the default bean, GreetingAlt is the alternative.

Test class:

```java
public class GreeterTest {

    private Greeter greeter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        try (WeldContainer container = new Weld().disableDiscovery()
                .addBeanClass(Greeter.class)
                .addBeanClass(Greeting.class)
                .addBeanClass(GreetingAlt.class)
                .addAlternative(GreetingAlt.class).initialize()) {
            greeter = container.select(Greeter.class).get();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void hiShouldContainMock() {
        assertThat(greeter.hi(), containsString("Mock"));
    }
}
```

Main classes:

```java
public class Greeter {
    @Inject IGreeting iGreeting;
    public String hi() { return iGreeting.greet("John"); }
}
```

```java
@Default
public class Greeting implements IGreeting {
    @Override public String greet(String name) { return "Hello " + name; }
}
```

```java
@Alternative
public class AltGreeting implements IGreeting {
    @Override public String greet(String name) { return "Mock " + name; }
}
```